# Transformar em um array uma variável do PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma variável em JavaScript que é uma string `"13:00:00"`, porém eu gostaria de passar ela para o PHP e fatiar ela  em um array , separando pelo `":"` porém a função do `explode` não funciona com o seguinte código:

```
<script>

    fin = "02:00:00";

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $fin = "<script>document.write(fin)</script>";       

    $tfin = explode(":", $fin);

    echo "<pre>";        
    var_dump($tfin);
    echo "</pre>";

    ?>


</body>
```

Como devo proceder para fatiar essa string?

Comment: porque não usa o `split()` do js? qual o motivo de passar para o php?

Comment: Bom, eu estou desenvolvendo um jogo,e conforme o jogo ocorre,tenho uma função que cronometra o tempo que o jogador percorreu para terminar o game, aí então gostaria de pegar essa variavel do JS,e passar para o php para adicionar ao banco de dados, porém me falaram para trabalhar com timestamp porque depois tenho um ranking e preciso ordenar em relação ao menor tempo

Comment: Usa ajax para isso ou envia esse valor atraves de um form.

Comment: Do JS pro PHP só tem jeito se for com Ajax. Sua pergunta não está muito clara se é PHP->JS ou JS->PHP...

Comment: Além do mais, porque a função `explode` não está funcionando? Retorna algum erro? O que aparece ali quando faz um `var_dump`?

Answer (score 2):

O PHP é uma linguagem de servidor, ou seja, o script é enviado para o servidor, é processado e depois retorna o resultado da saída, já o javascript é uma linguagem cliente, ela não é enviada para o servidor processar, então não tem como capturar desta maneira como está querendo, a menos que use o valor já processado via GET, PUT, POST ou fazendo um PARSE do documento em si. Como você pode resolver o problema, enviando isso via AJAX:

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['fin'])) {
$fin = $_POST['fin'];
 $tfin = explode(":", $fin);

    echo "<pre>";        
    var_dump($tfin);
    echo "</pre>";
die();

}
?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
       var fin = "02:00:00";
       var data = {fin:fin};
       $.post('<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; ?>', data, function(e) { 
        document.write('<html><body>'+e+'</body></html>');
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Outra maneira e usar o *explode* do javascript, a função `split()`:

```
 <body></body>
      <script>
      var fin = "02:00:00";
        var arrFin = fin.split(":");
        var out = '';
        for (var i in arrFin) {
            out += i + ' <font color="#888a85">=&gt;</font>'+
            ' <small>'+ typeof arrFin[i] +"</small> "+
            "<font color=\"#cc0000\">'" + 
            arrFin[i] + 
            "'</font> <i>(length="+arrFin[i].length+")</i>\n";
        }
        var pre = document.createElement('pre');
        pre.setAttribute('class','xdebug-var-dump');
        pre.setAttribute('dir','ltr');
        pre.innerHTML = out;
        document.body.appendChild(pre);
     </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como a sua variável está em JavaScript faça o `replace` da mesma forma, tome cuidado com as camadas de variáveis.

```
    <script>
            var fin = "02:00:00";
            res = fin.replace(/\:/g,'.')
            document.getElementById("novotempo").innerHTML = res;
    </script>
<body>
<pre id='novotempo'></pre>
</body>
```

Se precisar passar ela para *server-side* dá uma olhada em métodos AJAX.

Comment: Oi, Dom, as saudações são consideradas ruído e normalmente são removidas quando algum editor vai fazer um *upgrade* no post. É só clicar acima do avatar do editor em "Editada tal-hora" para ver o histórico da edição. Não duvide que se tiverem novidades ou problemas vão te perguntar aqui num comentário ;)

Comment: Não compreendi a resposta, você mencionou `split`, mas usou `replace`.

Comment: Desulpa estava trabalhando em um outro código e acabei fazendo confusão com o que estava escrevendo.. Resposta editada para futuros usos.

Comment: Uma nota @Dom, `document.getElementById` só funciona depois que o elemento existir, na ordem que você fez `document.getElementById("novotempo")` vai retornar `null`.

Comment: Desculpa, isso mesmo guilherme, estou trabalhando melhor nas minhas respostas aqui no stack flow para tentar cobrir todos os pontos .. :) ... Obrigado.